# SEF : URL shows user email - Routing

Tags: url, sef

I am working on an ecommerce joomla site and I am having some trouble with SEF URLs. When I turn this functionality ON in the Global Configuration of Joomla Backend, it appends user's email address (Seller) in the end of url. IfI keep this OFF then it doesn't show users' email.

Here user is the seller who has listed its property on the site. It sounds very scary to expose seller email address on its listing page.

I am not sure what causing this problem, I recently upgraded the J! to 3.8.6 and started seeing this trouble. Please let me know if I am making some mistake or any remedy/workaround. Do I need to make any changes in the htaccess? How does native SEF of joomla works?

Joomla Ver- 3.8.6
PHP ver- 7.0.28

Answer (score 1):

Which eCommerce component you are using ?, It may be the configuration of that component which appending the seller email_id to non-sef url.

Check the configuration of the component and you may find that they have something.

Let me know if this solves your problem :)